# How to calculate the number of combinations of $x$ integers, each with a value between $y$ and $z$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, arithmetic, combinations

For example, if I have 4 integers, and each can be between 0 and 36, how many combinations are there?

If the numbers have appeared before, but in a new order, then this still counts as a new combination e.g

$$1,5,3,4$$
$$1,5,4,3$$

Are different combinations.

So how many combinations all together will there be?

Also, how can I write an algorithm that will give me all of these combinations? I need to write some code that will cycle though every combination. My best attempt so far is:

```
start
a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0

increment d by 1 until d=36
increment c by 1 and then repeat the last step
repeat this until c=36
increment b by 1 and repeat the last 3 steps
repeat this until b=36
increment a by 1 and repeat the last 4 steps
repeat this until a=36
```

However I do not know if this will even give me every combination. I just cant wrap my head around it. I also do not know if this is a very efficient algorithm. In code this will most likely be implemented with nested for-loops which may take a long time. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why isn't it just $37^4$?

Comment: What do you mean by "between inclusive"?

Comment: I meant if they can also be $0$ and $36$ which I realized they can by your pseudocode.  So I edited it.  Answer is $37^4$ no?

Comment: That makes sense. Cheers.

Comment: You should look into "The Art of Computer Programming" volume 4 (combinatorial algorithms).  There are a number of slick algorithms for generating all combinations.  I'm not sure if you actually mean combination here (you are allowing repeats... and the order does matter?).  Nested for loops may not be "efficient" but you're unlikely to do better since there is low overhead with the loops and there are just a lot of "combinations" to generate.

Answer (score 1):

Your psuedocode should be nested loops, with optional indentation for clarity.

> $$\sum_{a=0}^{36}\sum_{b=0}^{36}\sum_{c=0}^{36}\sum_{d=0}^{36} 1 =\quad\begin{array}{|l}\textrm{Let n=0}
> \\
> \textrm{For a = 0 to 36 step 1}
> \\
> \quad\textrm{For b = 0 to 36 step 1}
> \\
> \qquad\textrm{For c = 0 to 36 step 1}
> \\
> \qquad\quad\textrm{For d = 0 to 36 step 1}
> \\
> \qquad\qquad\textrm{n = n+1}
> \\
> \qquad\quad\textrm{Next d}
> \\
> \qquad\textrm{Next c}
> \\
> \quad\textrm{Next b}
> \\
> \textrm{Next a}
> \\
> \textrm{Return n }
> \end{array}$$

And clearly that is just counting $37^4$, isn't it?

Comment: I wrote almost this exact code in MATLAB. But I also had `combination(n,:)=[a,b,c,d];` just underneath `n = n+1`, to get an array of every combination of the 4 numbers. However this has been running for half an hour and it still hasn't completed. This is strange because 37^4 isn't really that big of a number for a computer.